# Flutter app crash on Firestore transactions

Tags: flutter, transactions, google-cloud-firestore, crash

I am running transactions with Firestore on my app.

It is within a loop, and with every input, I will run the transaction once.

With 10-15 inputs, my app runs normally. However, when I have 25-30 or more inputs, it crashes and android studio loses connection with the app.

*** First throw call stack:
(
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x00000001136568db __exceptionPreprocess + 331
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x0000000112c01ac5 objc_exception_throw + 48
    2   CoreFoundation                      0x0000000113656662 +[NSException raise:format:arguments:] + 98
    3   Foundation                          0x000000010fc42834 -[NSAssertionHandler handleFailureInFunction:file:lineNumber:description:] + 166
    4   Runner                              0x000000010d7153fc _ZN8firebase9firestore4util8internal4FailEPKcS4_iRKNSt3__112basic_stringIcNS5_11char_traitsIcEENS5_9allocatorIcEEEE + 268
    5   Runner                              0x000000010d71556a _ZN8firebase9firestore4util8internal4FailEPKcS4_iRKNSt3__112basic_stringIcNS5_11char_traitsI<…>
Lost connection to device.